# Leetcode online Find the judge, graph with highest degree

Tags: java, algorithm, programming-challenge, graph

Here is the problem.

> In a town, there are N people labelled from 1 to N.  There is a rumor
>   that one of these people is secretly the town judge.
>
> If the town judge exists, then:
>
> The town judge trusts nobody.
>
> Everybody (except for the town judge) trusts the town judge.
>
> There is exactly one person that satisfies properties 1 and 2.
>
> You are given trust, an array of pairs trust[i] = [a, b] representing
>   that the person labelled a trusts the person labelled b.
>
> If the town judge exists and can be identified, return the label of
>   the town judge.  Otherwise, return -1.
>
> - Example 1:
>
>   Input: N = 2, trust = [[1,2]]
>     Output: 2
> - Example 2:
>
>   Input: N = 3, trust = [[1,3],[2,3]]
>     Output: 3
> - Example 3:
>
>   Input: N = 3, trust = [[1,3],[2,3],[3,1]]
>     Output: -1
> - Example 4:
>
>   Input: N = 3, trust = [[1,2],[2,3]]
>     Output: -1
> - Example 5:
>
>   Input: N = 4, trust = [[1,3],[1,4],[2,3],[2,4],[4,3]]
>     Output: 3
>
> Note:
>
> - 1 <= N <= 1000
> - trust.length <= 10000
> - trust[i] are all different
> - trust[i][0] != trust[i][1]
> - 1 <= trust[i][0], trust[i][1] <= N

And here is my solution.

(Logic :- Check the degree of every node, +1 for incoming and -1 for outgoing. If any node is having degree as N-1 then that is the node.)

```
public int findJudge(int N, int[][] trust) {
        // Create graph of N and then check degree, should be N-1
        final int NOT_FOUND = -1;
        final int trustArrayLength = trust.length;


        // Degree array should have value starting from 1 to N+1
        final int[] degreeArray = new int[N + 1];

        for (int i = 0; i < trustArrayLength; i++) {
            int[] itemInTrustArray = trust[i];

            // Since its outbound connection, decrease the degree by 1.
            degreeArray[itemInTrustArray[0]]--;

            // Since its inbound connection, increase the degree by 1.
            degreeArray[itemInTrustArray[1]]++;
        }

        // Now iterate though the degreeArray to find the index having degree as N-1.
        for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
            if (degreeArray[i] == N - 1) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return NOT_FOUND;
    }
```

Pleae let me know, the area of improvement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a wonderfully succinct solution. I will make one point:

```java
final int[] degreeArray = new int[N + 1];
```

This creates a never-used int at degreeArray[0]. I understand that this was a choice so as to be able to use a simple access by value of the trustees:

```java
degreeArray[itemInTrustArray[0]]--;
```

In the interest of creating the minimum number of objects necessary, and thus using the least memory possible, I would recommend initializing degreeArray to length N

```java
final int[] degreeArray = new int[N];
```

And then left shifting your insert by value statements

```java
degreeArray[itemInTrustArray[0]--]--;
degreeArray[itemInTrustArray[1]--]++;
```

and finally updating your final for loop to account for this change to the zero-based indexing inherent to arrays

```java
// Now iterate though the degreeArray to find the index having degree as N-1.
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
```

Since you are working with int primitives, the math operators here would add only a near-vanishing amount to overall runtime, if that is a concern.

Comment: Thank you, it was really helpful.

Comment: Great!! solution as I wondering why everyone is initializing it as N+1

Comment: Great!! but this doesn't work, can you please share full code